# Perfectly balanced sets of complex numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Suppose that $X$ is an inclusion-minimal finite set of non-zero complex numbers
such that $\sum\limits_{x\in X}x^n=0\ $ for infinitely many integers $n$.

> 1. Can the cardinality of $X$ be a composite number?
>
> <del>2. Can $X$ be something different from $\root^p\of c$
> (for some $c\in\mathbb C$ and prime $p$)?</del>

(*Inclusion-minimal* means that the number of $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\sum\limits_{x\in Y}x^n=0$ is finite for any proper subset
$Y\subset X$.)

Comment: For question $2$: consider $X := \{1, \zeta_{2i}\}$ for any integer $i$. Then for any $i|n, 2i\not|n$, we have $\sum_{x \in X} x^n = 1 + (-1) = 0$.

Comment: When you say "inclusion-minimal", what do you mean precisely? Do you mean that any subset doesn't satisfy the same equation for the same $n$? That for any subset, the corresponding set of $n$ must be finite?

Comment: Thanks! Actually, we can take even $\{1,i\}$ (where $i^2=-1$). I have edited the question.

Comment: $e^{i\pi k/17}$, $k=0,\dots,16$. (Just $\pi$ instead of $2\pi$.)

Comment: What if you take all 8 primitive roots of unity of degree 15, along with all 6 primitive roots of degree 7?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: Doesn't work: $X=\{\zeta_7,\zeta_{15},\zeta_{15}^{-1}\}$, where $\zeta_i$ is a primitive $i$-th root of unity. Then $\sum_{x\in X}x^n=0$ whenever $n\equiv35\pmod{7\cdot15}$, so your example isn't inclusion-minimal.

Comment: @AntonKlyachko That set doesn't work; $\{1, e^{i\pi k/17}\}$ satisfies the equation for $n \equiv 17 (\mod 34)$.

Comment: You are right. We should take $e^{2i\pi k/17^2},\ k=0,\dots,16$. Does this work? (This is just an example showing that there exists an "exotic" perfectly balanced set of any prime cardinality --- a response to Ilya's deleted comment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, thank you Gerry Myerson for bringing this problem to my attention at West Coast Number Theory 2019.

The answer to this question 1 is **No**.

**Edit on 12/26** : With a few more detailed analysis of the paper by Lam and Leung, it is possible to complete the proof, a crucial point is indicated by ***bold face italic***.

We prove that under the assumptions of this problem, $|X|$ must be prime.

**Step 1 : Reduction**

Let $|X|>2$ and $\zeta_N=\exp(2\pi i (1/N))$.

The sequence $s_n=\sum_{x\in X} x^n$ satisfies a linear recurrence relation. By [Skolem-Mahler-Lech theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Mahler%E2%80%93Lech_theorem), there is an arithmetic progression $\{an+b\}_{n\geq 0}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ with $a>0$, $b\in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
s_{an+b}=\sum_{x\in X} x^{an+b} = 0 \ \textrm{for all} \ n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$

**Step 2 : Vandermonde**

Let $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$. The result from Step 1 forms a Vandermonde system
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ x_1^a & x_2^a & \cdots & x_k^a \\ x_1^{2a} & x_2^{2a} & \cdots & x_k^{2a} \\
\vdots& \ddots& \cdots& \vdots \\
x_1^{(k-1)a} & x_2^{(k-1)a} & \cdots & x_k^{(k-1)a}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1^b \\ x_2^b \\ \vdots \\ x_k^b \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Since $x_i\neq 0$, the Vandermonde matrix must be singular. This yields $x_i^a = x_j^a$ for some $i\neq j$. Without loss of generality, assume that $x_1^a=x_2^a$. Then we may rewrite the system as 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ x_2^a & x_3^a & \cdots & x_k^a \\ x_2^{2a} & x_3^{2a} & \cdots & x_k^{2a} \\
\vdots& \ddots& \cdots& \vdots \\
x_2^{(k-2)a} & x_3^{(k-2)a} & \cdots & x_k^{(k-2)a}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1^b+x_2^b \\ x_3^b \\ \vdots \\ x_k^b \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
If $x_1^b+x_2^b=0$, it yields a shorter vanishing sums in the expression of $s_{an+b}=0$. So, we must have $x_1^b+x_2^b\neq 0$. Thus the above Vandermonde matrix is also singular, and we obtain another $i\neq j$ (both $\geq 2$) with $x_i^a=x_j^a$. Repeating this process, we obtain 
$$
x_1^a = x_2^a = \cdots = x_k^a. 
$$
Dividing by $x_1$, we may assume that all members of $X$ are roots of unity.

**Step 3 : Vanishing sums of roots of unity**

We refer to the results of this paper: T. Y. Lam, K. H. Leung, ['On the vanishing sums of roots of unity'](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869399980894?via%3Dihub)

Let $s_b=0$ from Step 1 be written as a vanishing sum of roots of unity. In this paper, the vanishing sums of roots of unity $\alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_k=0$ is called *minimal* if no proper sums vanish. It should be noted here that repetition is allowed. By the inclusion-minimal assumption, $s_b=0$ should be a minimal vanishing sum of roots of unity.

By Corollary 3.2 of the paper, we may assume (up to a rotation) all the roots of unity are $\zeta_N^s$ where $N=p_1p_2\cdots p_r$ is square free, $p_1<p_2<\cdots <p_r$ are primes. Let $G=\langle g\rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $N$  generated by $g$.

Let $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_N]$ be defined by the $\mathbb{Z}$-linear group-ring homomorphism such that $\varphi(g)=\zeta_N$. Let $G=H\times P_r$ where $H=\langle g_{N/p_r} \rangle \simeq\mathbb{Z}/p_1\cdots p_{r-1}\mathbb{Z}$ and $P_r=\langle g_{p_r} \rangle\simeq\mathbb{Z}/ p_r \mathbb{Z}$.

We write the vanishing sum $s_b=0$ as an element $v=\sum_{i\leq N-1} v_i g^i$, $v_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ of the group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$ such that $\varphi(v)=0$. Note that the coefficients of $v$ must be nonnegative. The element $v$ can also be written as
$$
v=h_0 + h_1 g_{p_r} + \cdots + h_{p_r-1} g_{p_r}^{p_r-1},
$$
with $h_i\in \mathbb{Z}H$. Here the coefficeients of $h_i$ are also nonnegative.

We have $\varphi(h_i)\in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{N/p_r})$ for all $i\leq p_r-1$. By ***linear disjointness*** of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{N/p_r})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p_r})$, we must have
$$
\varphi(h_0)=\varphi(h_1)=\cdots=\varphi(h_{p_r-1}).
$$
**Case 1**

If $\varphi(h_0)\neq 0$, this means that each $h_i=\sum_{j\leq N/p_r -1} h_{ij} g_{N/p_r}^j$, $h_{ij}\in\mathbb{Z}$, contains at least one positive coefficient. Let $h_{ij_i}$ be such positive coefficient of $h_i$. Then a sub-sum $$
h_{0j_0} g_{N/p_r}^{j_0} +h_{1j_1} g_{N/p_r}^{j_1} g_{p_r}  + \cdots +  h_{(N/p_r-1)j_{N/p_r -1}} g_{N/p_r}^{j_{N/p_r-1}}g_{p_r}^{p_r-1}
$$
has positive coeffients.

Taking $N/p_r$-th powers of each group element and applying $\varphi$, we obtain a vanishing sub-sum of powers
$$
1+\zeta_{p_r}^{N/p_r} + \cdots + \zeta_{p_r}^{(N/p_r)(p_r-1)}=0.
$$

**Case 2**

If $\varphi(h_0)=0$, then we may repeat the above argument with fewer prime factors, e. g. $N$ is replaced by $N/p_r$.

Therefore, under the inclusion-minimality assumption, $s_b=0$ yields a minimal vanishing sum of roots of unity 
$$
1+\zeta_p+\cdots + \zeta_p^{p-1}
$$
for some prime $p$ up to a rotation.

Comment: If $x_1^b+x_2^b=0$ and $x_1^a=x_2^a$ then $s_{an+b}=0$ gives $\sum_{x\in X} x^{an+b} = \sum_{j=1}^k x_j^{an+b}= (x_1^b+x_2^b)x_1^{an}+\sum_{j=3}^k x_j^{an+b}$

Comment: Thanks! But how $x_1^b+x_2^b+x_3^b+x_4^b=0$ "yields a shorter vanishing sum"?

Comment: The next one in the iteration, we consider  $x_1^b+x_2^b+x_3^b=0$ or $x_3^b+x_4^b=0$. Rewriting the summation expression for $s_{an+b}$ again, gives shorter sum.

Comment: Happy New Year, Sungjin! In Step 3, do you mean that any inclusion-minimal vanishing sum of roots of unity is of the form $g+g\zeta_p+\cdots + g\zeta_p^{p-1}$? It seems strange because in the paper you cited some asymmetric inclusion-minimal vanishing sums are discussed...

Comment: In your problem, the requirement that any proper subset gives finitely many $n$'s with $n$th power sum vanish, allows us to conclude that your set $X$ must be of the form.

Comment: Happy new year! The asymmetric ones has a proper subset whose sum of powers vanish infinitely often. So, they are not inclusion-minimal.

Comment: Yes, I see. So, you prove that *a set $X$ is perfectly balanced (i.e. satisfies the condition from my question) if and only if $\{x^k\;|\;x\in X\}=\root^p\of c$ for some integer $k$,  prime $p$, and complex $c$*, right? It would be the answer to a more sensible version of Question 2.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.